# What is the equivalent of ctools_export_load_object()?

Tags: 9, chaos-tool-suite

In Drupal 7, I would use the following code.

```php
$objects = ctools_export_load_object($type, 'names', array($name));
```

What is the equivalent code in Drupal 9?

I unsuccessfully tried with the following code.

```php
$objects = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($type)->load();
```

I didn't find any post describing the Drupal 9 equivalent would be.

Comment: You need to pass an ID to `load`.

Comment: Probably best to also share what the value of `$type` is.

Comment: Are you trying to load an entity like a node or a user? In that case, the Drupal 7 function would be `entity_load()`, not `ctools_export_load_object()`, which doesn't necessary load what for Drupal 9 is an entity.

Comment: If you are trying to load all the Drupal 9 entities of the same type (nodes or users, for example), then you need to use `loadMultiple()` instead of `load()`, in the last snippet you shown.

Comment: As @sonfd said, it's important to know what `$type` contains, to give better answers.